# What is the logic behind JavaScript In-/ Decrement? Could someone clearify this?

Tags: javascript

**++    Increment**

```
x = ++y     // When y = 6   x = 6   
x = y++     // And y = 6    x = 5
```

**--    Decrement**

```
x = --y     // When y = 4   x = 4   
x = y--     // When y = 4   x = 5
```

Could someone clearify this?
Thank you.

Comment: There is a [pretty good documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Increment_and_decrement) on this (and more). Also with examples and a good explantation for everything.

Answer (score 2):

The only slightly tricky case there is:

```
x = --y     // When y = 4   x = 4
```

You must be looking at `y` **afterward**. If you looked at `y` **before**, you'd see a `5`.

The basic rules for prefix decrement (`--y`) and postfix decrement (`y--`) are:

- Either way, the operand (`y` in this case) is decremented by 1. The only difference is what the result of that expression (`--y` or `y--`) is.
- If the operator comes **before** the operand (`--y`) it's a "prefix" decrement: The decrement happens **before** the result of the expression is taken. So the result is the value of `y` after it was decremented.
- If the operator comes **after** the operand (`y--`) it's a "postfix" decrement: The decrement happens **after** the result of the expression is taken. So the result is the value before it was decremented.

Examples:

```js
var x, y;

y = 5;
snippet.log("Before prefix decrement: y = " + y);
x = --y; // Result is the value **after** the decrement
snippet.log("After prefix decrement: x = " + x + ", y = " + y);

y = 5;
snippet.log("Before postfix decrement: y = " + y);
x = y--; // Result is the value **before** the decrement
snippet.log("After postfix decrement: x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gah! Had my explanations reversed briefly. Apologies.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is  very eay to understand. So there is no logic?  Only rules to follow?

Comment: @Rich: The rules *are* the logic. :-) The logic is: If the operator is in front of the variable, the operation happens *before* the result is determined. If the operator is *after* the variable, the operation happens *after* the result is determined. So it's simple: Just read left-to-right to determine what happens first. (This is specific to the increment/decrement operators. Overall rules of expression evaluation are slightly more complex.)

Answer (score 2):

In both cases `y` will have the same final value. The only difference will be in the return value of the expression itself.

- `++y` will *return* the value **after** incrementing.
- `y++` will *return* the value **before** incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

When the operator precedes the variable, it changes its value before any processing. When the variable precedes the operator, the value is changed after processing.

`y = ++x` is identical to:

```
x = x + 1;
y = x;
```

and `y = x++` is identical to:

```
y = x;
x = x + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your main question is:

> The logic behind ...

The answer to that part specifically are processors. Many have had the `INC` and `DEC` instructions for a very long time and since C was created to match the processor instructions, it was thought that having operators such as `++` and `--` would help in optimizing some code.

```
INC WORD [BP+4]    ; increment value at address BP+4 by one

DEC WORD [SP+16]   ; decrement value at address SP+16 by one
```

RISC processors generally require you to use `ADD` and `SUB` instead. The result is pretty much the same in modern processor because speed of execution of such instructions was greatly enhanced, especially with large instruction caches.

Java and JavaScript are spawned of C and thus inherited these.

Specifically, there is the 68000 processor that has instructions such as:

```
MOV.W D1, (A1)+    ; copy D1 at address A1, then increment A1 by size of D1

MOV.W D2, -(SP)    ; decrement stack by size of D2, then copy D2 at address SP
```

which include *hidden* increment (the +) and *hidden* decrement (the -) in the instruction.

In these cases, C matched the processor behavior perfectly. You could write something like:

```
*a1++ = d1;

*--sp = d2;
```

And each line becomes just one instruction in assembly language. Notice that the `++` and `--` used with the stack work like a charm:

```
*--sp = d1;  // move the stack pointer, then save value on the stack
...          // do some work
d1 = *sp++;  // restore from the stack, then move the stack pointer back
```

Here we want to use register d1, so we save it on the stack, the automatic pre-decrement works exactly as required. Then before leaving the function, we restore from the stack, again, the automatic post-increment works exactly as expected. The INTEL processors have specialized instructions instead: `PUSH` and `POP`. But that's the same concept.

Of course, with C++ and other object oriented languages (including Java and JavScript), that has evolved quite a bit now and it is easy to lose the reason why we have had these `++` and `--` operators.